# Adding a new block to a category page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, phtml, html

Hi I've created Ajax menu in a .phtml file using some lib and JavaScript & html code however I called the file for 1 product type. I don't want it to appear except in this product.
However the location is going in a different location than where I want this block to be. I'm quite new to magento so it's not easy for me to figure out the file locations in server side or where to find each file separate to put the code in directly.[image]

this picture
is where the file appears when I called the block in the product page.

but I want it as this :
[image]

any advice on how to actually change block position and where?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

**This solution if for Magento 2.0 version**

It will be better if you'll describe how did you add your phtml file to that page.

I see you are on category page, so you need to make changes in `catalog_category_view.xml` located in: `app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout`

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           layout="**your_layout**"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="bundle.product.grid"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::**your-file**.phtml" 
before="category.products" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

> template="Magento_Catalog::**your-file**.phtml"

Here you define where your phtml file is (with the block you want). You can change Magento_Catalog to whaterver module you want to use.

**For version 1.9.x:**

create `local.xml` file in your `theme_folder/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">    
    <catalog_category_default>
       <reference name="content"
           <block type="core/template" name="your.custom.block" template="ajaxmenu/ajax_menu.phtml" before="product_list">
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

Using `reference` and `before="product_list"` you tell magento where to show your block.

Comment: {{block type="core/template" template="ajaxmenu/ajax_menu.phtml"}}

Comment: that's how I added the file into the page. I added the file to server then created static block and called the file using the code above

Comment: Is it posible to use the refrence container inside the custom layout on this category ? under custom layout?

Comment: @M.Ghaly please look at new answer description. I've changed it acording to your magento version

Comment: **For custom Layout** use it like this:

`<reference name="content"
           <block type="core/template" name="your.custom.block" template="ajaxmenu/ajax_menu.phtml" before="product_list">
        </reference>`

Answer (score 1):

is it posible to use this code in custom layout like this[image]: